# How to make elements overflow on two lines manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have these blue square that I want to overflow horizontally on two lines (each time a new square is created it alternates between being created in the line above and the line below and so on) you can use CSS , Sass, JavaScript or jQuery .. I want this for my project as this is ONLY the front end and the back-end code generates new squares ... and thanks a lot ...

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<style>
.test {
background: blue;
width: 372.1478174125px;
height: 230px;
margin: 5px;
display: inline-block;

}
.horizontal {
background: gray;
height: 640px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class= "horizontal">
<div class = "test"> hello </div><div class = "test"> hello </div>
<div class = "test"> hello </div>
<div class = "test"> hello </div>
<div class = "test"> hello </div>
<div class = "test"> hello </div>
<div class = "test"> hello </div>
    <div class = "test"> hello </div>
    <div class = "test"> hello </div>
    <div class = "test"> hello </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this fits your requirements.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrNqwo?editors=1100

This is the style i changed.

```
.horizontal {
    background: gray;
    height: 640px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Increase the height in .horizontal class to 750px.